# data-ng-bind from $scope controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, compilation, scope, ng-bind

I'm lost, could you help me?

I have a value in the $scope which is retrieved from JSON file:

in Controller:

```
$scope.scopeTitle = title;
```

in JSON file:

```
"title": "fruit.ID || 'Empty'"
```

The `fruit.ID` is retrieved from backend, and I want to display it's ID in my HTML.

Everything is works fine if in my HTML I do sth like:

```
<span class="navbar-brand"  data-ng-bind="fruit.ID || 'Empty'" />
```

the result on the HTML is:

```
FRUIT/12 or Empty <- and it's good
```

If I want to pass it via $scope, like this:

```
<span class="navbar-brand"  data-ng-bind='scopeTitle' />
```

it's not working, the result on the HTML is:

```
fruit.ID || 'Empty' <- it's not good
```

My HTML is generated in template in directive and I'm using a $compile function to compile the HTML code.

How to write the ng-bind expression properly to achieve the result via $scope?

Comment: Can you try using `$eval` to see if it would work. It's almost impossible to evaluate a string in Angular expressions. You can check out `$eval` [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$eval)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use $scope.$eval in your controller and use this to declare scopeTitle

```
$scope.scopeTitle = $scope.$eval(title);
```

**update : *
you can see that you were assigning "fruit.ID || 'Empty'" as a string as an expression so you need to use $eval

and why not using something like this

```
<span class="navbar-brand">{{scopeTitle}}</span>
```

Comment: There are problems with the `$eval`. I'm getting an error: `Unknown provider: $evalProvider <- $eval`, but I'm injecting the `$eval` into my Controller. 
`I can't use just {{scopeTitle}}` because it won't bind from backend (I tried it also and it won't work)

Comment: sorry dude my bad ,, I fixed it

Comment: it's not a service it's a function in scope ,, I wrote that by mistake

Comment: It working great! That's what I want. muchas gracias! :D

Answer (score -2):

try

```
data-ng-bind={{scopeTitle}}
```